# Problems with backgroundcolor in R Shiny

Tags: r

I am developing an R Shiny app, but I have a problem with the background color:

[BACKGROUND EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLc3o.png)

I specify it as white. Attached to a mini application of my program.

```
   ui <- dashboardPage(
    skin="red",
    dashboardHeader(title = "Análisis RFM"),
    
    
    dashboardSidebar(
        disable = FALSE,
        sidebarMenu(
            menuItem("RFM Vehículos", tabName = "sub_11", icon = icon("tachometer-alt"))
            
            #  )
        )
    ),
    
    
    dashboardBody(
        shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
        tags$head(tags$style(HTML(
            '.myClass {
        font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 50px;
        text-align: left;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
        padding: 0 15px;
        overflow: hidden;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        float: right;
      }
      
      .container-fluid {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
      }
      .skin-red .main-header .navbar {
        background-color: #af2a19;
      }
      .modal-dialog {
        width: 80%;
        margin: 30px auto;
      }
      .spinner-bbede7502999167361fd86b847d3d8e8{
      /*.shiny-spinner-output-container {*/
        position: initial;
        transform: translateY(70%);
      }
      
      .leaflet-left .leaflet-control{
        visibility: hidden;
      }
}
      
      
      
    '))),
        tags$script(HTML(paste0('
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("header").find("nav").append(\'<span class="myClass">', 'Fecha Actualización: ',
                                Sys.Date(), '</span>\');
      })
     '))),
        
        tabItems(
            tabItem("sub_11",
                    fluidPage(
                        div(
                            fluidRow(
                                column(4, h3("Resumen del RFM"),
                                       style="color:#8c8c8c;text-align: center;"),
                                column(4, dateRangeInput(
                                    inputId = "fecha_vehiculos",
                                    label = "Seleccionar rango de fecha:",
                                    start = Sys.Date()-365,
                                    end = Sys.Date()
                                )), 
                                column(4, 
                                       tagList(
                                           actionButton("btnGenerarBaseGestion", "Calcular RFM", icon("check")), 
                                           br(), 
                                           shinyWidgets::progressBar(
                                               "loadchanges", value = 0,
                                               status = "primary",
                                               display_pct = TRUE
                                           )
                                       )  
                                       
                                       
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
            )
        
            
        )))




server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    
  
                
                
                
               
    
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But the borders do not change to white color, could you help me with it.

What CSS property should I use so that the background format of my shiny R application is completely white, without the borders that are in the attached image?

Comment: Please share your app as a mini app ie ui/server with the error and that we can run.

Comment: I just added it to the questions, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. change your `fluidPage` to `div`
2. Use `.content-wrapper` to add white background CSS to your style

```r
        tags$head(tags$style(HTML(
            '.myClass {
        font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 50px;
        text-align: left;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
        padding: 0 15px;
        overflow: hidden;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        float: right;
      }
      
      .container-fluid {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
      }
      .skin-red .main-header .navbar {
        background-color: #af2a19;
      }
      .modal-dialog {
        width: 80%;
        margin: 30px auto;
      }
      .spinner-bbede7502999167361fd86b847d3d8e8{
      /*.shiny-spinner-output-container {*/
        position: initial;
        transform: translateY(70%);
      }
      
      .leaflet-left .leaflet-control{
        visibility: hidden;
      }
      
        .content-wrapper, .right-side {
            background-color: #ffffff;
        }      
      
    ')))
```

You have a syntax error in `tags$style`, I corrected.

[image]